# Specific match between two CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv, match

I have two CSV files like this:

CSV1:

```
Name
test;
test & example;
test & example & testagain;
```

CSV2:

```
Name
test1;
test&example;
test & example&testagain;
```

I want to compare each line of CSV1 with each line of CSV2 and, if the first 5 letters match, write the result.

I'm able to compare them but only if match perfectly:

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path ".\client.csv" -Delimiter ";"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv ".\client1.csv" -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($record in $CSV1) {
    $result = $CSV2 | Where {$_.name -like $record.name}
    $result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so with `Compare-Object` and a custom property definition.

```
Compare-Object $CSV1 $CSV2 -Property {$_.name -replace '^(.{5}).*', '$1'} -PassThru
```

`$_.name -replace '^(.{5}).*', '$1'` will take the first 5 characters from the property `name` (or less if the string is shorter than 5 characters) and remove the rest. This property is then used for comparing the records from `$CSV1` and `$CSV2`. The parameter `-PassThru` makes the cmdlet emit the original data rather than objects with just the custom property. In theory you could also use `$_.name.Substring(0, 5)` instead of a regular expression replacement for extracting the first 5 characters. However, that would throw an error if the name is shorter than 5 characters like in the first record from `$CSV1`.

By default `Compare-Object` outputs the differences between the input objects, so you also need to add the parameters `-IncludeEqual` and `-ExcludeDifferent` to get just the matching records.

Pipe the result through `Select-Object * -Exclude SideIndicator` to remove the property `SideIndicator` from the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($record in $CSV1) {
    $CSV2 | Where {"$($_.name)12345".SubString(0, 5) -eq "$($record.name)12345".SubString(0, 5)} |
        ForEach {[PSCustomObject]@{Name1 = $Record.Name; Name2 = $_.Name}}
}
```

or:

```
... | Where {($_.name[0..4] -Join '') -eq ($record.name[0..4] -Join '')} | ...
```

Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet:

```
$CSV1 | Join $CSV2 `
    -Using {($Left.name[0..4] -Join '') -eq ($Right.name[0..4] -Join '')} `
    -Property @{Name1 = {$Left.Name}; Name2 = {$Right.Name}}
```

All the above result in:

```
Name1                       Name2
-----                       -----
test & example;             test & example&testagain;
test & example & testagain; test & example&testagain;
```